# Powershell File Rename Date/Time

Tags: powershell

I have used a script from a previous post and modified it slightly:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\test\*.txt" | ForEach-Object {          
Rename-Item $_.FullName "$BackupFolder$($_.BaseName -replace " ", "_" -replace '\..*?$')-$(Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy").txt"
}
```

However:

Current renamed file: `test-ddmmyy.txt`
Required Format: `testddmmyy.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work.

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\test\*.txt" | ForEach-Object {          
Rename-Item $_.FullName "$BackupFolder$($_.BaseName -replace " ", "_" -replace '\..*?$')$(Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy").txt"
```

Your dash was coming in from just before `$(Get-Date`. Remember, when passing things in double-quotes as a parameter, anything that's not a variable or is not within parenthesis and preceded by `$` will be treated as a string character.

In the below script:

```
$test='test';"$test-$(Get-Date -F 'ddMMyyyy')"
```

`$test` will be expanded into its value `'test'`, `-` will be left alone since it is neither a variable nor a part of an expression, and `Get-Date -F 'ddMMyyyy'` will be processed and return its output since it is set apart as an expression with `$(`...`)`. This will result in:

```
test-24112013
```

Get rid of the dash, and...

```
$test='test';"$test-$(Get-Date -F 'ddMMyyyy')"
```

....outputs...

```
test24112013
```